# Is there a way to completely disable all forms of microphones/audio recording devices?

Tags: spyware, surveillance, countermeasure, audio

There are a variety of anti-audio recording devices out there, including white noise generators which can block audio recording equipments especially phones. What specs should I be looking for if I want a device that will work against all audio recording devices? Is that even technically possible?

Comment: There are more possible way to measure vibrations and thus audio you can imaging. Scientist often find ways to abuse various hardware for doing so. If I remember correctly there was a paper about audio recording by using computer hard discs as vibration sensors and other crazy stuff.

Comment: That's pretty cool! However, would it be possible to have a device that distorts these vibrations enough to throw of the ability of any recording device within a physical space to record audio?

Comment: An EMP would probably do the job. It may also have undesirable side-effects.

Comment: Yeah, EMP would likely be overkill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the method of noise generation it could be trivial to filter out meaningful audio from the white noise.

You might consider [sweeping](https://www.counter-intelligence.com/countermeasures-debugging-spying-devices-tscm-technical-surveillance-countermeasures/) the area for  bugs but this is not foolproof as some bugs can turn on and off or switch frequencies. This will not protect against devices like the [laser microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone) which can be used to eavesdrop by pointing a laser beam at a window.

You must also be vigilant about easily overlooked listening devices like a smartphone or laptop which should not be in your vicinity and need to have a mechanical kill switch for the mic at the very least.

The ideal counter-surveillance method would likely involve a sealed, sound-proofed facility which has been turned into a Faraday cage and has strict controls on entry and exit. This is exceedingly difficult in practice as there are thousands of ways your perimeter can be breached, and it is virtually impossible to ensure a passage for authorized individuals while also guaranteeing that they won't be used as a mule to smuggle in a micro listening device.

I think a low-tech solution works best for this situation: communicate by writing on paper and burn it later. It is much easier to control the dispersion of light waves compared to audio waves.

Comment: Thank you for this, and you bring up an interesting point regarding laser devices. I've heard of these before and it seems that there are some sites selling devices like these online.  However they tend to be quite pricey. Doing a bit more research on this and it seems like the tech isn't fully developed yet? Or is it already commercially viable (assuming that these online sites aren't just marketing a laser device that only kind of works).

Answer (score 0):

In short. No you can’t do this.

In general you could make a signal that makes a ADC go crazy basically destroying the recording capability.

However you can apply analog filter techniques to limit or eliminate this effect.

Also you haven’t eliminated non digital recording technology.  (There is no reliable way to do this).

In short it all depends on what you want to defend against.  And why.

Comment: I'm looking to safeguard business discussions against spying bugs, particularly audio recording devices either planted within a room, or those that have been brought in by the other party. If we just assume audio recording devices within physical spaces, and not over the phone, would it be possible to employ any technique to defeat all of them?

Comment: You could try any of those white noise generators as you listed. The thing is that how effective they are is impossible to predict and has to be tested. There are also possible legal precedents that apply (you should contact a lawyer for legal advise). Technically ADC have known limits that can be exploited like that. But I would never claim that anything would work for anything.